# Non-Pythagorean proof for the square root of 2 and solution to YBC7289

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview

My name is J. Frederic Teubner I am an independent researcher. I wish to publish a proof for the non-Pythagorean solution to the Babylonian tablet [YBC7289](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_Babylonian_Collection) and am currently inquiring as to whether or not this has already been accomplished and published in which case it would be unseemly for me to publish it as my discovery. Since the same discovery can be made near simultaneously by disparate individuals it may be that it has been published. I have researched everything I can find on the subject and the consensus is "No". I have inquired at several internet math sites and they say "not to their knowledge has the problem been solved". Do you happen to know if the solution to YBC7289 has been formally demonstrated and if so by whom?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question in research in the history of mathematics. I edited to give a modicum of context and a link to the Wikipedia page for the Yale Babylonian Collection. I also removed the sign-off, since such information is most usefully placed in the user profile. I make no comment on the proposed solution nor the website of the OP.

Comment: I'm a little confused - when you say "solution to the Babylonian tablet," what does that mean? It doesn't seem to me that the tablet poses an explicit question, it just provides an approximation to $\sqrt{2}$. (By the way, I think that Babylonian mathematics is incredibly interesting, but I'm not sure this is the appropriate site for this question.)

Comment: @Noah, all I could think of was that OP has found a way to dissolve that tablet.

Comment: I do think, however, that if the OP is asking whether anyone else has simultaneously claimed the same result as him, then we have a hard time answering this. The answer may well be "No, everyone agrees that the tablet describes an approximation to $\sqrt{2}$".

Comment: Well, one possible question I could see is "What algorithm did the authors of the tablet use to get these approximations?" That could be very interesting, and I have no idea if there is work on that already - google doesn't help, and the language on this page - http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/Euclid/ybc/comments.html - to me suggests that it is unknown.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Possibly, although I'm sure actually dissolving the tablet would precipitate a violent reaction.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for HSM, [*History of Science and Mathematics*](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Joseph I didn't realise there was such an SE site! I then suggest, if no answers are here forthcoming in the next few days, that the OP flags for moderator attention and asks for a migration.

Answer (score 1):

Some  relevant references can be found at http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/convergence/the-best-known-old-babylonian-tablet (The Best Known Old Babylonian Tablet? by Janet L. Beery and Frank J. Swetz). Hope they will be helpful. Especially reference [3]: http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Elpachter/128a/Babylonian_sqrt2.pdf (Square root approximations in Old Babylonian mathematics: YBC 7289 in context, by D.H. Fowler and E. R. Robson).

P.S. see also  https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/babylon-and-the-square-root-of-2/